# How to use JDBC to send Google From response to Cloud SQL?

Tags: javascript, jdbc, google-docs, google-cloud-sql, google-forms

I work for a non-profit that holds free sports and physical activity events. I'm am trying to set up a system to store and collect information about our membership and the events we hold, using Google Docs as the user interface and Google Cloud SQL for data storage.

Like most non-profits, we do not have a lot of resources available for advanced computer programming. I would like to use Google Forms as a simple UI that our research and evaluation staff can use to build data collection tools without coding. The ease of access to the responses in Google Sheets is great; however, we hold a lot of events and will quickly exceed the 2 million cell limit. So, I think we will need to store the responses in a SQL database.

What I would like to do is modify the action performed on submit, such that the form:

1. Does NOT submit to a sheet
2. Connects to a SQL table (I've set this up on Google Cloud SQL)
3. Dumps the responses into the correct columns
4. If the form was modified, add any new columns to the table (like Forms does with attached sheets).

I know that Google Apps Script can connect to external databases through the JDBC service (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) and I know that I will need to use the getItemResponse method (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-stackoverflow/laLkcneaqZo/PfPKKYlmva8J) to execute this.

I have very little experience with Google Apps Script or JavaScript in general....basically, the most I've done is finish the Codecademy JavaScript course. However, I am a quick learner and I'm looking for a little example code that might get me started (remembering that I have almost no experience).

I've searched through this forum, GitHub and everywhere else I can think of, but cannot find something that is quite right. I'm mostly pointed to the JBDC documentation, but do not know how to use it. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Brett

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some articles about this at my blog, [Bit Vectors](http://bitvectors.blogspot.com). [This article](http://bitvectors.blogspot.com/2014/12/page1.html) might cover most of what you need. That specific article explains how to build a Google Apps Script solution tied to a Google Sheet file. The GAS solution front-ends Cloud SQL. The end-user sees a web page / form, and if you want, the Google Sheet itself. To answer your list items:

1) The web form does write to a sheet, but in the software, you can easily prevent this

2) The web form definitely connects to your Cloud SQL table / database

3) The solution writes to the table(s) / column(s) you want through stored procedures

4) The solution will not modify the data table structure if you change the form - you would have to handle this change yourself

See a demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEc8UV2geUY).

HTH!

- Frank